# Html Dropdowns - Calling Functions to generate the options on the lists

Tags: c#, html, drop-down-menu

I have a web application written in C# with an html front-end that I am updating. There is a form that has two drop down selections.

The first drop down needs to call a C# function and populate its options with the result (an IEnumerable, but I can change that if necessary)

When the first dropdown is selected I need it to trigger a function in the second dropdown that takes the selected option of the first box as an argument and again populates itself with the result.

So if my thing were about cars, it would, on loading the form, get a list of all the makes it has from the function (it has to be a function, not a db, this isn't something I can change) and when you select a make, it then uses that as an argument to populate all the models of car with that make into the second box.

So my question is - how can I accomplish this on an html form

Answer (score 0):

Cases like this are accomplished by filling the selects using JavaScript and Web Services asnychronously. So your C# app won't populate any of those selects directly but simpley calls the view. Then you trigger a JS-AJAX-operation to populate the first select. You then listen to the select-change-event of this control to again populate the next control.

This topic is too general to post a simple answer. You should take a look at [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses MVC, but I think it can be acheived the same way without MVC.

Make a function with javascript that gets the desired list, clear the list and then with a foreach loop add each item to the list
example:

My select elements (codD and codC):

```
<div class="row" id="listD">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width: 85px;">Distrito</span>
                            <select class="form-control" id="codD" name="DD">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br id="brD" />
                <div class="row" id="listC">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="min-width: 85px;">Concelho</span>
                            <select class="form-control" id="codC" name="CC">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now a function that changes codC

```
function ChangeConcelhos(dist) {
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("MudarConcelho", "Tabelas")", { distrito: dist },
            function (fooList) {
                $("#codC").empty();
                if (fooList.length > 0) {
                    $.each(fooList, function (i, foo) {
                        $("#codC").append("<option value=" + foo.CC + ">" + foo.Desig + "</option>");
                    });
                }
            });
    }
```

Don't forget to add the event change of codD

```
(function() {
  $("#codD").change(function () {ChangeConcelhos($("#codD").val())});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a onChange event to the combo you want to get value from: `onChange="load_cascaded_combo(this.value)"`
And here is the jQuery:

```
function load_cascaded_combo(val) {  

                    var ddl = $('#drops'); // this is the box you want to load
                    ddl.empty(); // clear current content
                    var project = document.getElementById("select1");// this is the combo you get value from
                    var stringArray = new Array();
                    stringArray[0] = project.value;
                    var postData = { values: stringArray };                    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/SomeControler/SomeMethod",
                        data: postData,
                        success: function (data) {
                                var i = 0;
                                $.each(data.Result, function () {
                                    ddl.append(
                                     "<option value='" + data.Result[i] + "'>" + data.Result[i] + "</option>"
                                    );
                                    i++;
                                });                           
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        traditional: true
                    });
                }             
            };
```